# Primefaces: DataTable selection is not working with ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Sorry for my english. I use `DataTable` selection and I want to use `DataTable` selection with ajax:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="testTableId" var="testTable" value="#{testMB.entityList}"
                 selection="#{testMB.selectedList}" rowKey="#{testTable.id}"
                 tableStyleClass="table table-hover table-bordered">

        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
        <p:column headerText="testName">
            #{testTable.name}
        </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton process="testTableId" action="#{testMB.deleteSelected}" value="It is working"/>

            <p:commandButton process="testTableId" action="#{testMB.deleteSelected}" value="It is not working">
                <p:ajax update="@form" />
            </p:commandButton>              
        </f:facet>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

If I click to button `It is working` then it is working. But if I click to ajax button `It is not working` then it is not working.

How can I use it with ajax?

Comment: With PrimeFaces `p:commandButton`, AJAX is enabled by default. Your second button is equivalent to `<p:commandButton update="@form"...`. If you do not specify `update`, it defaults to `@none`. To emphasize: both of those buttons are submitting using AJAX. The only difference is that you've specified which component(s) to update using `update`.

Comment: If I use as `<p:commandButton process="testTableId" update="@form" action="#{testMB.deleteSelected}" value="It is working"/>` it is not working as ajax. It is working as without `update="@form"`.

Comment: Again, and to emphasize: Primefaces' `commandButton` uses [AJAX by default](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml). Your "It is working" button is already using AJAX. Also, why have you specified `process`? Do you know [how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces)?

Comment: @DavidS Thank you very much. I used `h:commandButton` instead of `p:commandButton` in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go back to the PrimeFaces showcase and learn about the PrimeFaces dataTable and ajax selection. Nowhere in the showcase can examples like you do be found in combination with ajax selection.

Comment: Thank you. I used `h:commandButton` instead of `p:commandButton` in my project. It is my problem.

Comment: ??? Then your question is totally out sync with what you actually mean. With an `h:commandButton` there is no ajax at all. I'm going to flag the question and my answer to be removed due to a total lack of clearity